# Sequelize - How to get reviews for post with likes count for each review

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a function like this.
It receives comments on the post.
And it doesn't work - it makes endless requests.

```
async getReviews(entityId) {
        let settings = {
            include: [{
                model: db.User,
                attributes: ['nickname', 'img', 'role'],
            }, {
                attributes: [],
                model: db.Like
            }],
            attributes: {
                include: [[db.Sequelize.fn("COUNT", db.Sequelize.col("likes.id")), "likesCount"]]
            },
            raw: true,
            nest: true
        }
        
        const reviews = await db.Review.findAll({
            where: {
                parentId: entityId,
                type: 'review',
                isDeleted: false
            },
            ...settings
        });
        
        await db.Review.includeNested(reviews, settings);
        
        return reviews;
    }
```

If we remove this line, the function returns one comment with counted likes.

```
await db.Review.includeNested(reviews, settings);
```

And if you remove this block:

```
            attributes: {
                include: [[db.Sequelize.fn("COUNT", db.Sequelize.col("likes.id")), "likesCount"]]
            },
```

... then the function will return an ARRAY of comments.
Why does the like counting make only one comment come back?

How to get an array of reviews with counted likes?
Here is the nesting function:

```
this.includeNested = async function f(reviews, settings) {
                const idArr = reviews.map(el => el.id);
                const children = await models.Review.findAll({
                    where: {
                        parentId: idArr
                    },
                    ...settings
                });
    
                reviews.forEach(review => {
                    review.children = children.filter(ch => ch.parentId === review.id);
                });
                
                if (children.length)
                    await this.includeNested(children, settings);
            }
```

endless query strings while full code:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `review`.`id`, `review`.`level`, `review`.`isDeleted`, `review`.`parentId`, `review`.`text`, `review`.`type`, `review`.`createdAt`, `review`.`updatedAt`, `review`.`userId`, COUNT(`likes`.`id`) AS `likesCo
unt`, `user`.`nickname` AS `user.nickname`, `user`.`img` AS `user.img`, `user`.`role` AS `user.role` FROM `reviews` AS `review` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `user` ON `review`.`userId` = `user`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `likes` AS `likes`
ON `review`.`id` = `likes`.`reviewId` WHERE `review`.`parentId` IN (NULL);
```

without nested:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `review`.`id`, `review`.`level`, `review`.`isDeleted`, `review`.`parentId`, `review`.`text`, `review`.`type`, `review`.`createdAt`, `review`.`updatedAt`, `review`.`userId`, COUNT(`likes`.`id`) AS `likesCo
unt`, `user`.`nickname` AS `user.nickname`, `user`.`img` AS `user.img`, `user`.`role` AS `user.role` FROM `reviews` AS `review` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `user` ON `review`.`userId` = `user`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `likes` AS `likes`
ON `review`.`id` = `likes`.`reviewId` WHERE `review`.`parentId` = '099d8a11-0fbe-420b-9a18-514989388c83' AND `review`.`type` = 'review' AND `review`.`isDeleted` = false;
```

without `include: [[db.Sequelize.fn("COUNT"...`:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `review`.`id`, `review`.`level`, `review`.`isDeleted`, `review`.`parentId`, `review`.`text`, `review`.`type`, `review`.`createdAt`, `review`.`updatedAt`, `review`.`userId`, `user`.`nickname` AS `user.nick
name`, `user`.`img` AS `user.img`, `user`.`role` AS `user.role`, `likes`.`id` AS `likes.id`, `likes`.`userId` AS `likes.userId`, `likes`.`reviewId` AS `likes.reviewId` FROM `reviews` AS `review` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `user` ON
`review`.`userId` = `user`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `likes` AS `likes` ON `review`.`id` = `likes`.`reviewId` WHERE `review`.`parentId` = '099d8a11-0fbe-420b-9a18-514989388c83' AND `review`.`type` = 'review' AND `review`.`isDeleted` = fa
lse;
```

Comment: I would suggest to add column for like, even after we resolve this one subqueries will slow down app in future.

Comment: Do you mean the column for the like count in the review table?

It violate the principles of working with the databasem, doesn't it? We create a countable field.

Comment: Still not resolved the question, how can I draw additional attention to the question?

Comment: can you share query that is generated using sequelize (logging: true)

Comment: Likes has a different table correct ?

Comment: Yeah, Like has relation many to one for Review And User

Comment: I tried the same syntax and it just works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding group by to reviews

```
const reviews = await db.Review.findAll({
    where: {
        parentId: entityId,
        type: 'review',
        isDeleted: false
    },
    // add group by id
    group: ["id"],
    ...settings
});
```